# Swift , What is the reason for the imagepicker to flip

Tags: ios, swift, localization, imagepicker

Iam building an ios app in arabic , but for some reason when i present an imagepicker the photos collection is flipped as it was transformed by (x : -1)[image: here this is the image picker]

Comment: Arabic is a right-to-left language, so the system adjusts everything accordingly

Comment: thanks for your comment , so what should I do if want to avoid this problem

Comment: You should probably just go with it... I have no idea how to force left-to-right on the image picker